# Angularjs + Slim Framework: RESTful Authentication with php sessions

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, slim

I'm trying to build a little API service for a website, which frontend will be in Angularjs. Everything works fine unil… I try to implement authentication!
I created a simple auth method to check if user is logged in:

```
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || $_SESSION['user_id'] == null){
        printError(401, 'You must login to view this content');
        $app->stop();
    }
}
```

This works fine if I use Postman REST client: I can log in, and only when I'm logged in I can access to secured routes. But when I put the code in Angularjs (using $http.post method), I can login (successful msg is shown) but then is like the `$_SESSION` variable remains not set.

So, two questions:

- Is it right to use `$_SESSION` to store variables and check wether user is logged in or not?
- Why this works with Postman and not in Angularjs?

Thank you,
Camillo

Comment: Sessions plus REST equals problems.  Look at using authorization headers.  Basically, ask slim for an authorization token (probably a Json Web Token) and then include it in subsequent requests.  Plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, I've done it via JWT.